# How do I make each line from a file list into separate variables?

Tags: python, algorithm, variables, file-handling

How do I make each line from a file into a separate variable?

For example, if this was my text file...

> Taylor Swift, 1989
>
> Beyonce, 1982
>
> Zara Larsson, 1998
>
> Demi Lovato, 1993

How would I make each line of this file into 4 separate variables? With each line being a string. With them being variables I am able to print each separate line at any part of the program by printing it’s variable.

Comment: How will the program come up with the variable names? Are you sure you are not looking to change them into a list?

Comment: I would use a `dict` with multiple keys rather than trying to create multiple variables...

Comment: There are many examples on line of how to read from a file.  How is it that none of them helped you to write even a single line of code toward a solution?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here. 
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first, read the file into a string line by line; then convert the string to a variable. In python, you can do the following

```
i = 0
with open("file.txt", "r") as ins:
    v = "var"+str(i)
    for line in ins:
       exec(v+"='str(line)'")
    i+=1
```

another approach is to read the lines into a list:

```
with open("file_name.txt", "r") as f:
    line_list = []
    for line in f:
        line_list.append(line)
```

your first line can be accessed in line_list[0], and second line in line_list[1] and so on

Comment: Thank you but how will I now identify or name each separate variable so I can easily print them out later on in my code? For example if the first line was a variable called “line1” and I could just say print(line1) and it would print the first line for me

Comment: @Charlotte do **not** use this approach. It is unsafe, this a bad habit to get in to, and also, it leads to messy code. Instead, use a container like a `list`

Comment: can you just name the variables "line"+str(i) where increments as you create the variables? if all you want is to read the lines into an ordered data structure, I would suggest using a list rather than create separate variables

Comment: Please tell me what to do then I have no idea. The file is supposed to represent a list of songs and the task is to write a code which allows the user to create a playlist- choosing which tracks from the file list they would like to add and adding them to this new playlist, which will then be printed out at the end of the code. Any idea on how to do this? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: I edited my answer to include a method to read lines into a list. you can learn more about list structure here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: @Charlotte I have provided the answer to your question.  If you do not understand it, feel free to ask questions or reference the documentation

Comment: @Charlotte currently on my phone, but there are a couple answers that show you how to read the lines into a list, this one included. Do **not** use the approaches with `eval` to create dynamic variables, it's a very very sloppy way of doing things.

Answer (score -1):

Variables are out of the question, but they can be stored in different positions in a list

```
file = open("filepath","r")
data = file.readlines()
file.close()
```

data should be each line as an element in a list

Answer (score -1):

Most likely you actually want to create a dictionary.

```
vars = []
artists = {}

with open ('random.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        vars.append(line.strip().split(','))
for var in vars:
    artists[var[0]]= int(var[1])

print(artists)
```

Comment: Please just don't recommend this.